# stmt->execute() (Array to string conversion error)

Tags: php, mysqli, insert

Team, I am trying to insert a register in a mysql db, and while using mysqli I am getting an error on `execute()`

> Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\InsereSite.php
>   on line 19 Call Stack execute ( ) ..\InsereSite.php:19

I am not sure why it tries to make this conversion but, at any case, here is the code. Please tell me more datails as you can.

```
<?php
function InsertSiteDb($site_novo){

    if(!isset($_POST['sites'])) {
        echo " Voce precisa estar logado para acessar essa pagina";
        header('Location:sellsite_login.html');

    }else{

        $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'sellsites');


        $query = "INSERT INTO pages (url,file,public,price) VALUES (?,?,0,0)";
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query);

        $stmt->bind_param('ss',$_SESSION['url'],$_SESSION['nomesite']);
        //$stmt->execute();

        $stmt->close();


    }


}
?>
```

Here is where the InsertSiteDb is called:

```
<?php

    session_start();
    $sites = $_POST['sites']; //o que foi digitado no form será postado
    var_dump($sites);
    $sites = explode(";",$sites);


foreach ($sites as $site) {
        $recebesite_html[] = file_get_contents($site); 
}                                                   

$contador = 0;

 foreach ($recebesite_html as $site_novo){
    $pos = strpos($site_novo, "<title>"); 
    $pos_final = strpos($site_novo,"</title>");
    echo $pos.$pos_final;

    $pos += 7; 
    $tamanho = $pos_final -$pos;

    $nome=substr($site_novo,$pos,$tamanho);
    $_SESSION['nomesite'] = $nome;
    $_SESSION['url'] = $sites;
    $retorno = file_put_contents($nome.".html",$site_novo);
    echo $retorno;
    var_dump($site);
 }

include ("InsereSite.php");
$registro_site=InsertSiteDb($_SESSION['nomesite']);


?>
```

Comment: Please mark line 19 with a comment

Comment: Worked. It really inserted to mysql without that line. Thank you for help, however could you tell me why it doesn't need the execute here? This is what is described on php docs:
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php

Comment: It should require a execute call, as I said please mark line 19 with a comment

Comment: Ok sorry, I commented that, and it was inserted into the database. However the url was saved as "Array" instead of saving the String with url.

Comment: I mean mark line 19 in your question with a comment like: `//This is line 19`

Comment: Replace `$stmt->execute();` with `if(!$stmt->execute()){trigger_error("there was an error....".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);}` and see why it's failing. Also make sure you've started the session.

Comment: Are `$_SESSION['url']` and `$_SESSION['nomesite']` strings?

Comment: @ Rizier123 I did that now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1) From Fred-ii-

```
     if(!$stmt->execute()){
trigger_error("there was an error.:".$mysqli->error, E_USER_WARNING);
    }
```

2) The issue is that either `$_SESSION['url']` or `$_SESSION['nomesite']` is an array rather than a string. Add a code block *ABOVE* your `$query =` call to state:

```
if (is_array($_SESSION['url']) || is_array($_SESSION['nomesite'])){
print "Data is an array:<br>";
var_dump($_SESSION);
}
```

The error "Array to string conversion" is because one of these two $_SESSION values are array values and the PHP is trying to fit these array values into strings as defined in the `bind_param` method.

## UPDATE:

Looking at your updated code view, the `$sites` variable which is later used in `$_SESSION['url']` is clearly an array, so look to use one value from the array or imploding the array or using a similar method to transform it into a string.

Comment: Appreciate the help of all of you.
Just did:
$sites=implode(" ",$sites); and it fixed the error. You were right with your statements. I hadn't noticed that.

Comment: no worries, glad you got it fixed, @MarceloMoraes :)

Comment: Gotta love error checking ;-) So useful when developing; *cheers* @Martin

Comment: So many questions on SO can be solved if the OP read an error output, and I see (your) good advice on comments, if I'm writing an answer I think they should be included and made more prominent. hah... I also hate reading `code` in comments!